# How to form a data using MultiPart/form-data in Play scala?

Tags: scala, junit, specifications

I don't know how to send multipart data in play scala Test case(Specs2).
In my project, method receives multipart data, code look like this

```
def school_register() = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request => 
}
```

In my test case using Specs2 how to form multipart data manually and want hit the school_register method. Once method hitted values are inserted into DB. I have four parameters regno=100,name="xxxx", address="xxx", std=5. Without multipart its working but i have to use multipart data.
Without Multipart i'm using like this

```
"com.example.schooladmin" should {
                "responds with 200 for addSchoolRegister action with all required parameters" in new WithApplication {
                       val controller = new TestController()
                        val result =  controller.school_registerr() .apply(FakeRequest().withFormUrlEncodedBody(
  “Reg No” -> “100”,“Name” -> “XXX”,“Address” -> “XXXXX”,“std” -> “5”))
                        status(result) must equalTo(OK)
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'm doing this, I create a temporary file and I post it with `withMultipartFormDataBody`:

```
val tempFile = TemporaryFile(new java.io.File("../server/idCards/5e7b7c6c-98b3-4245-a5fb-405c9cc904f4"))
val part = FilePart[TemporaryFile](key = "picture", filename = "the.file", contentType = Some("image/jpeg"), ref = tempFile)
val formData = MultipartFormData(dataParts = Map(), files = Seq(part), badParts = Seq(), missingFileParts = Seq())

val Some(result) = route(FakeRequest(userDomain.routes.UserController.createIdCard())
  .withMultipartFormDataBody(formData))

status(result) mustEqual OK
```